# createBlocksFromInnerBlocksTemplate with nested [core/group] elements

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

WordPress 5.6 has a new Block API. With "createBlocksFromInnerBlocksTemplate" we are able to create create blocks from InnerBlocks template.

I tried this function with the template underneath and it works without any problems.

```
const template = [
   [ 'core/paragraph', { content: 'Example block' } ],
   [ 'core/paragraph', { placeholder: __( 'Example content.' ) } ],
],

createBlocksFromInnerBlocksTemplate( template )
```

Now, i want to create a nested `core/group` that contains 2 columns. Each columns should have a `core/heading` and `core/paragraph`.

I started with this example underneath:

```
const template = [
   [ 'core/group', { layout: { type: "default" } ]
],
```

This creates a core/group as i want but how to go one with to columns and create for each columns again innerBlocks?

The result should look like:

```
<core/group>
  <core/columns>
      <core/column>
          <core/heading>
          <core/paragraph>
      </core/column>
  </core/columns>
  <core/columns>
      <core/column>
          <core/heading>
          <core/paragraph>
      </core/column>
  </core/columns>
</core/group>
```